# html contract form Japanese

Tags: php, html, email, outlook

I'm try to make a contract form for my html site.
When custome input there info and send it, then the info will send to my company mail box (TestOulookMailBox.info@test.net), and 1 mail to confirm the detail to custome who send it.

The code is work fine with g-mail and English. But my company mail box is Oulook and using Japanese. The mail in Japanese is broken.

```
<?php if(!empty($_POST["send"])) {
    $userName = $_POST["userName"];
    $userCompanyName = $_POST["userCompanyName"];
    $touserEmail = $_POST["userEmail"];
    $userPhone = $_POST["userPhone"];
    $userMessage = $_POST["userMessage"];
    $userSubject = "Mail from Test page";
    $toadminEmail = "AdminMailBox.info@test.net";
    $adminSubject = "お問い合わせありがとうございます";
    $adminName = "株式会社テスト";

    $userHeaders = "From: ". $userName.
    "\r\nお名前：". $userName.
    "\r\n会社名：". $userCompanyName.
    "\r\nメールアドレス：". $userEmail.
    "\r\n電話番号：". $userPhone.
    "\r\nお問い合わせ内容：". $userMessage.
    "\r\n"."---------------------------------------------------";

    $adminHeaders = "From: Test Page".
    "\r\n". $userCompanyName. " 様".
    "\r\n"."下記の内容で受け付けました。".
    "\r\n"."2営業日程度で内容を確認の上ご返答させていただきます。".
    "\r\n"."なお、内容にってはご返答できかねる場合もございますので、あらかじめご了承ください。".
    "\r\n"."---------------------------------------------------".
    "\r\nお名前：". $userName.
    "\r\n会社名：". $userCompanyName.
    "\r\nメールアドレス：". $userEmail.
    "\r\n電話番号：". $userPhone.
    "\r\nお問い合わせ内容：". $userMessage.
    "\r\n"."---------------------------------------------------";
  
    if(mail($toadminEmail, $userSubject, $userName, $userHeaders)) {
        mail($touserEmail, $adminSubject, $adminName, $adminHeaders);
        $message = "お問い合わせありがとうございます";
    }
}
```

I want it just a simble mailing to my company outlook mail box.
Thank for your help.

Comment: Broken in what way? You probably need a `Content-type:` header to specify the character set.

Comment: The text I get in Outlook is like this:
"粋繧上○蜀・ｮｹ・壻ｸ玖ｨ倥・蜀・ｮｹ縺ｧ蜿励￠莉倥￠縺ｾ縺励◆縲"
Can I asking how to set Content-type: for my case ?

Answer (score -1):

The reason for this issue is that the encoding of the mail is not compatible with Outlook. You may need to change the encoding settings in Outlook or in your HTML code to use **Unicode (UTF-8)**, which is a universal encoding standard that supports most languages.

To change the encoding settings in Outlook, you can follow these steps:

- Open Outlook and click on File > Options > Advanced.
- Under International options, click on the Preferred encoding for outgoing messages drop-down list and select Unicode (UTF-8).
- Click OK to save the changes.

To change the encoding settings in your HTML code, you can add the following meta tag in the head section of your HTML document:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

This tag specifies the character encoding for the HTML document, which is **UTF-8** in this case.

Comment: It doesn't look like they're sending HTML email, so `<meta>` won't work.